# I'm not able to use assets in my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a react app basically it is a practice project but I want to use images and audios stored in assets folder I am not able to use there assets in my project I don't know how can I use it.

this is my github link : [github](https://github.com/Keshav-Rajput-31/todo-list.git)

please help.

I tried to import it but its not working

Comment: In which page you have import the assests?

Answer (score 1):

Import your file like below -

```
import comleteSound from '../assets/sounds/comlete.mp3';

//you might want to change the file name from comlete.mp3 to complete.mp3
//in your assets/sound folder
```

This will resolve your import issue but once you import you will get the following error
[image]

You can refer this link to fix it

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12810

Another alternative to access your images and mp3 if you want to reduce the relative path is to move your assets' files to public folder- ***/public/sounds/compete.mp3***

```
import comleteSound from '/sounds/compete.mp3';
```

Here's an import of image on your github code-

[image]

code - `<img src={"/done.svg"} alt="done" width={100} height={200}></img>`

Comment: still not working

Comment: Updated the answer by showing your github code, just move your assets to public folder. Your public folder should be inside todo-list folder and not inside app folder.